# Removing '\n' from scraped Table

Tags: scrape

Hello Following is my code and I am tried my luck using Split, Replace command and still getting '\n' in my table.

My code is below.

url = "https://shared.websol.barchart.com/quotes/quote.php page=quote&sym=ng&x=13&y=8&domain=if&display_ice=1&enabled_ice_exchanges=&tz=0&ed=0"

res = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')

Header = soup.findAll('tr', limit=2)[1].findAll('th')

column_headers = [th.getText() for th in soup.findAll('tr', limit=2)[1].findAll('th')]

print(column_headers)

data_rows = soup.findAll('tr')[2:]

i = range(len(data_rows))

for td in data_rows:

```
row = td.get_text()

print(row,end= '\n')
```

Output of code is still in format below but appearing as rows and columns with a little bit scattering.

**I would like to eventually export this to Pandas for analysis**

\n    Aug \'19 (NGQ19)\n    2.688s\n    +0.001\n    2.691\n    2.691\n    2.670\n    355\n    2.687\n    05/25/18\n

Comment: Please format the post to make the code more readable.

Comment: Done. I am sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: Any response please to my question?